# Open several vim-encrypted files with the same password

Tags: encryption, vim

Let's say I have three files in the same folder, `a.txt`, `b.txt` and `c.txt`, all of them encrypted (with Vim) with the same password ("asdf" for example). Is there a way to open the three of them entering the password only once?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The encryption password used by Vim for encrypting and decrypting files is stored in the `key` variable, see [`:help encryption`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#encryption). This variable is normally local to a Vim buffer, so Vim uses a unique password for each encrypted file that is opened or saved. Vim will prompt for a new password when a different encrypted file is opened for the first time.

To make the password global, enter

```
:set key=asdf
```

in Vim, where `asdf` is the password. After explicitly giving the `key` variable a value like this, Vim will use the same password for subsequent encrypted files that are opened with `:e` or `:n` in the same Vim instance.

The `key` variable can be set on the Vim command line used to open the files with

```
vim --cmd "set key=asdf" a.txt b.txt c.txt
```

**Beware:** this records the password in the clear to your shell history file (for example `~/.bash_history`) and to all other users on the system by simply looking at a list of running processes with `ps`.

Other solutions for encrypting files transparently with Vim are possible, the Vim wiki offers [this page of tips on encryption](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Encryption), including executing PGP or GnuPG automatically when opening and saving files based on the file extension.

Answer (score 2):

Type in the key before opening the first file with this cmd:

```
vim -c ":let &key=inputsecret('key=')|:bdel dummy" dummy a.txt b.txt c.txt
```

Edit 1. To answer question in the comment below. If you want the files open together in tabs, like vim -p a.txt b.txt c.txt

```
 vim -c ":let &key=inputsecret('key=')|:tab all|:bdel dummy" dummy a.txt b.txt c.txt
```

More options: `set viminfo= noswapfile bin cm=blowfish`

Needs a dummy file `dummy`, because the input dialog comes up only after the first file is loaded, even with --cmd. In this case, you have to type the key once.

Don't use *`*--cmd="set key=asfd"*`*; because process args can be seen with the ps command to others users, may get logged in syslog, and also saved in your bash_history.