# Encrypt all vim buffers with same password

Tags: encryption, vim

Setting aside weaknesses in vim's encryption algorithm and the security implications of using the same password for multiple files, is there any way to encrypt *all* Vim buffers with the same password without having to go through one-by-one and `:X` with `:w`? [This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/457130/open-several-vim-encrypted-files-with-the-same-password) shows how to bulk-decrypt with the same password, but I'm looking to bulk-encrypt.

Comment: Did you test the answer from the link you provided?  After doing `:n` is need to enter the key again

Comment: I see -- this is close but not ideal. The user still needs to cycle through every file individually to encrypt it (with `:n`) unless I'm missing something.